# Can't smooth my object

Tags: modeling, workflow, smooth

I'm quite new to Blender. I have a lot of experience with CAD software like Fusion360. But when it comes to detailed modeling, there are limits in this software.

So I decided to test Blender and it is awesome. But I think I'm on the wrong way? So I finished the first part and tried to smooth it. But the problem is, that I can't smooth it.

It would be awesome if someone could check it and maybe give me some advise to improve my work. Or the right tutorials.

[Download Blend File on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MmnpNfNnkmmQz7fddCI-2c-ZAEevB-S/view?usp=sharing)

---

[image: Sword red edge]

Thank you for your tips. I tried to get rid of all my problems :)
But there is one more edge which is red. How can I get rid of it?

And how do I fill this structure.

Thx again! The file is updated on google drive.

Comment: You did not follow the step with `A` then `M` > *Merge By Distance*. It merges 2000+ overlapping duplicate vertices. Then the other vertices that don't have a edge going from the sharp edge top to the bottom, just select them and press `X` > *Dissolve Vertices*

Comment: I followed your steps like you said.

I'm sorry for missunderstanding you, but nothing happens, when I'm doing it again. And about the edge: Should I just dissolve them, so I can put new verices there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have alot of overlapping duplicate vertices. To get rid of them, <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices followed by <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*. Then notice when you go into *Solid Mode* and tick the *Face Orientation* checkbox under *Overlays*, there are red faces instead of all being blue, which means their *Normals* are facing in the wrong direction. To resolve this, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (*Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*).

[image]

Now it will look like mostly blue. The red parts are the interior of the mesh since you have not closed the mesh yet, so that's fine.

[image]

But you're not done yet, you have another problem with the mirroring. There is a gap so you have to either move the vertices closer to the mirroring edge or increase the *Merge* distance to close the gap.

[image]

And then you have overlapping faces. Notice that when you select this face, how that it is not properly split by the edge highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Delete the face and fill in new separate faces by manually selecting 4 vertices at a time then press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill a face. There are also grid fill options you can explore under *Face > Grid Fill*.

[image]